# Beginner Asking: How do I get my android app to compile in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm going through a tutorial here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-development/.

I have finished the tutorial and I've set up my debug configuration. When I actually try to run the debugger I see a popup that says: "Your project contains errors. Please fix them before running your application."

In the "Problems" tab of eclipse, It says Errors 1 Item: Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the Console for output. The location of the error is listed as unknown. When i switch to console, this is what's in there:

```
[2010-11-13 19:34:36 - SDK Manager] Warning: Error parsing 'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\android-sdk_r07-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-2\sdk.properties': java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\android-sdk_r07-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-2\sdk.properties (The system cannot find the file specified).
[2010-11-13 19:34:36 - SDK Manager] Warning: Error parsing 'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\android-sdk_r07-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-5\sdk.properties': java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\android-sdk_r07-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-5\sdk.properties (The system cannot find the file specified).
[2010-11-13 19:34:36 - SDK Manager] Warning: Error parsing 'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\android-sdk_r07-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-6\sdk.properties': java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\android-sdk_r07-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-6\sdk.properties (The system cannot find the file specified).
[2010-11-13 19:35:25 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'FirstAndroid' based on Android 2.2,
[2010-11-13 19:35:25 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2010-11-13 19:35:25 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=160
```

I'm not sure what to do about this. Where would i get those files/What's the next step?

Comment: Do you have your android SDK properly configured in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had **exactly** this problem, and I can't say what is causing it (I will not start with suggestions of type "check that the SDK is installed properly") but I have received bugs that outputs **Unparsed aapt error(s)** on several occasions, mainly (but not only) related to the SVN plugin - committing one project when there are errors in another project in the workspace.

To fix this, I am deleting the project from the workspace (but not from the filesystem), and then importing it again, and it worked 100% of the time.

I hope it works for you too, and I also hope that someone may explain exactly what can cause these.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. i am brand new to the Eclipse IDE. How do i delete from workspace and not from filesystem? Is there a "remove" option in a menu somewhere?

Comment: on the left of the IDE is the list of projects. click with the mouse on the one that has the aapt error (whatever that error is) and click delete from your keyboard. A dialog will appear, with a checkbox to delete from the filesystem too. Don't check it of course, and click ok. Then File->Import->Existing projects into Workspace->select root directory-> and navigate to the workspace folder (where the project is) and select it's folder. It will be in your workspace too. This helps me always for these aapt-s, I hope it will for you too

Comment: just create an archive of the entire project's folder which you ca use as a backup if the delete procedure sounds dangerous to you, but if you don't check the delete checkbox everything is ok. You can import from the archive with the same procedure as for the folder, just choose the option to import from an archive instead from a folder. Using SVN is way better, but since you are not used to the IDE yet probably you are not using it yet.

Comment: @quakkels, recompiling usually works for me...doesn't happen anymore since i switched to Pulsar.

Answer (score 0):

i think your SDK is not properly plugged in. try reinstalling it